# python - numpy - many matrices multiplying many vectors

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have a set of many matrices each corresponding to a vector. I want to multiply each matrix by its vector smartly. I know I can putt all the matrices in a big block diagonal form, and multiply it by a big combined vector.

I want to know if there is a way to use `numpy.dot` to multiply all of them in an efficient way.

I have tried to use `numpy.stack` and the `numpy.dot`, but I can't get only the wanted vectors.

To be more specific. My matrices look like:

```
R_stack = np.stack((R, R2, R3))
```

which is

```
array([[[-0.60653066,  1.64872127],
    [ 0.60653066, -1.64872127]],

   [[-0.36787944,  2.71828183],
    [ 0.36787944, -2.71828183]],

   [[-0.22313016,  4.48168907],
    [ 0.22313016, -4.48168907]]])
```

and my vectors look like:

```
p_stack = np.stack((p0, p0_2, p0_3))
```

which is

```
array([[[0.73105858],
    [0.26894142]],

   [[0.88079708],
    [0.11920292]],

   [[0.95257413],
    [0.04742587]]])
```

I want to multiply the following: `R*p0, R2*p0_2, R3*p0_3`.

When I do the `dot` :

```
np.dot(R_stack, p_stack)[:,:,:,0]
```

I get

```
array([[[ 0.        , -0.33769804, -0.49957337],
    [ 0.        ,  0.33769804,  0.49957337]],

   [[ 0.46211716,  0.        , -0.22151555],
    [-0.46211716,  0.        ,  0.22151555]],

   [[ 1.04219061,  0.33769804,  0.        ],
    [-1.04219061, -0.33769804,  0.        ]]])
```

The 3 vectors I'm interested in are the 3 `[0,0]` vectors on the diagonal. How can I get them?

Comment: More details... Like a working example + your tries.

Comment: What have you tried (please post the code)? Can you give us some examples of input and expected output? what isn't working as expected?

Comment: @Mathieu just put the example. I accidentally posted before including my example.

Comment: Lots of extra calculations if you use `dot`, and extract a diagonal.  `einsum`  can do just the need calculations.  `matmul` can also be used - possibly with an added dimension.

Comment: `(R_stack @ p_stack)[:,:,0]` is faster.  Or in `einsum` (which now shortcircuits to @ if possible), `np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl', R_stack, p_stack)[:,:,0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You need to add a diagonal index on 1st and 3rd dimensions like so:

```
np.dot(R_stack, p_stack)[np.arange(3),:,np.arange(3),0]
```

Every row in the result will correspond to one of your desired vectors:

```
array([[-3.48805945e-09,  3.48805945e-09],
       [-5.02509157e-09,  5.02509157e-09],
       [-1.48245199e-08,  1.48245199e-08]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way I found is to use `numpy.diagonal`

```
np.diagonal(np.dot(R_stack, p_stack)[:,:,:,0], axis1=0, axis2=2)
```

which gives a vector in each column:

```
array([[0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0.]])
```